# Check validation and pervent form submitting into server in @Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a code in index.cshtml

```
 @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("ActionEvent", "Fielding", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onBDSuccessFunction", HttpMethod = "post" }, new { id = "frmField" }))
    { 
        @Html.Partial("../Fielding/_CreateOrEdit", Model)
    }
```

and in _CreateOrEdit

```
function onBDSuccessFunction(result, status, xhr) {
       var errorMessage = '';
       switch (String(result.Result).toUpperCase()) **2 cases from controller when Actionevent Method fired** {
        case "OK":
               var _msg = "Data Saved Successfully";
               alert(_msg);
               return true; **saved data into database only happens here**
               break;
           case "ERROR":
               if(result.Message=='1')
               {
               alert(result.Messag);
               return false; **prevent submiting form here**
               }             
       }

   }
```

Here i have 2 cases from ActionEvent Method Case OK and Case ERROR it returns result as Json

1. If Controller returns Case OK I want to save the entered details in the form into database
2. If Controller returns Case ERROR I dont want to save the entered details in the form into database

But in both cases the data saved into database .. but the validation fired message shows correctly..
What can i do for this.. please guide me..

Comment: Please also show your Razor/HTML form

Comment: `OnSuccess` is fired after the form has been submitted. Just make the decision to save or not save on the server when you post.

Comment: How can i make the decision to save or not save on the server when  post?

Comment: Well the method already makes the a decision whether to return "OK" or "ERROR".

Comment: ya , if it returns OK i want to save the data into database if wether it returns ERROR i want to prevent this.

Comment: The method currently determine whether its OK to save or not, so if its OK, then save it, otherwise don't, then return your message.